# Drupal 8 paragraph in rest export view

Tags: drupal-8, paragraph

I have a view with a rest export display used to retrieve a custom content type made by some fields and a paragraph.
I'm not getting how to output the paragraph in the view, I don't see the filed or any reference to the paragraph field.
What I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a `relationship` to your paragraph reference field, and then all of the paragraph fields will be available under `fields`.